# Is depicting Muhammad in animated cartoons or video games allowed?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, depiction

So, I know it is forbidden for a Muslim to draw a picture of Muhammad, and I think of the other Islamic prophets too. However, if someone were to an animated cartoon, weather drawn or computer made, about Muhammad, does this ban still count? And can the same be said about a video game depiction?

Comment: Any depiction of any prophet or messenger in any form is not allowed. See [To depict Muhammad or not](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/5576/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any depiction of prophet Muhammad is haram. Be it in animation, be it in any video, a picture in movie or any way. After-all, animation also has His depiction, so in all ways it is haram , to never draw him in any possible way.

And Allah knows the best