# Is it allowed to make Prophets in movie or book?

Tags: prophets, image

Prophets appeared in movies like Prophet Moses appeared in 'Prince of Egypt' if you have seen it before. Prophets' faces can be showed in child's books, some of books aren't. For example, Prophets' faces are covered. As long as I shouldn't be sure what they look like.

A movie called BILAL: A New Breed of Hero. Bilal was still there during the Prophet Muhammed's time. I've been always wanting to draw stories about Prophets. I'm not sure I will draw Prophets or cover their faces. Is it ok I can draw their fellows like Prophet Moses' mother and siblings, Bilal, their fellows except Prophets?

Comment: Some relevant posts http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12077/depicting-jesus http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1493/what-is-the-islamic-ruling-regarding-depiction-of-prophets-or-companions-of-prop?s=1|0.9264 http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23708/why-is-making-a-picture-of-mohammed-disrespectful?s=9|0.5253  http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/906/why-depicting-prophet-pbuh-in-movies-is-not-welcomed?s=15|0.2714 http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/869/is-drawing-people-prohibited-in-islam?s=39|0.0445.

Answer (score 0):

Is it permissible to make prophets in movies or books?
This is not a problem in itself from the religious point of view, as long as it does not include matters that are considered insulting and disrespectful according to custom, and does not conflict with the dignity of these nobles.

Ref: https://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/fa694#